# Is it a clean way to use threads for 100 independent small local search jobs?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, optimization, java-threads

Currently I'm working on an implementation of a search algorithm. In a specific step of the algorithm are over 100 objects (generated Solutions), improved by a local search. To speed up the algorithm, I want to use threads. So every local search should run in its own thread and as soon as every "search thread" is finished, the algorithm should go on.

Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    list[i].localSearch();
}
```

Question: Is it a good/clean way to start several threads for over 100 jobs? And how can I start new threads inside a for loop (variable i) without defining a new runnable class. Thx for your help.

Comment: Keep in mind that thread are efficient when their numbers are close to the number of CPU cores of the machine they are run.

Comment: I don't know which scheduling algorithm is used, but theoretically if I have 80 threads and only one process and four cores it should speed up the algorithm, shouldn't it?

Comment: It is not always true. It all depends on the type of tasks run. In many cases 80 threads can actually be slower than 4 threads.

Comment: You might want to use a threadpool and tune it to see how many threads are a good choice (it **may** be 100, but you can't know that without trying). As for @tsolakp, that "use the amount of cores you have" is a common misconception (one I already saw today even). It all depends on the CPU vs. IO boundedness of the tasks being done.

Comment: @Kayaman. You are right that to be totally correct I should have mentioned HyperThreading as well as along with cores. But I personally think that starting with number of cores (times 2 if there is HyperThreading) is a good point to see how much multi threading will help. That number should usually be good enough unless actual performance testing will show better efficiency with more threads.

Comment: @tsolakp The thread/cores correlation is only true for CPU bound computations.  When threads are blocking on external network calls, you can profitably have lots more threads.  When threads are blocking on disk I/O, the limit can depend on your disk drive.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good/clean way to start several threads for over 100 jobs?

indeed it is common to use multiple threads if you can divide the problem into parallel jobs

you have to consider - is your task compute bound (you are searching memory, doing computations,  ..) then you can use multiple threads, however as mentioned the number of threads should be close to number of cores (for pure compute tasks, you can experiment here)

if your task is reading from disk a lot, using more threads may even hurt the overall performance.

> And how can I start new threads inside a for loop (variable i) without defining a new runnable class.

I suggest to use an ExecutorService, which works as a job queue with processing pool of threads

there are plenty of [tutorials](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) just search some